# How can I mirror form responses on a completely different website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, velo

I'm creating a hotel website using WYSIWYG site builder, Wix (shame on me, I know). Like any hotel site, we want a bar form for customers to input their information to make reservations and such.

Here's the catch: our booking is run through an external reservations company, which means they have their own form to be filled out. What I'm looking for is some code that automatically auto-fills the information on the external party's form when the users hit submit.

As further explanation/illustration, if I have "Check in date" and "Check out date" on my form and the user fills out the information and hits submit on our site, I want it to auto-populate the information the user just filled out on the external party's form page (https://reservation.magnusonhotels.com/bbe/page1.aspx?hotelID=6666) so the user doesn't have to re-enter it. Is this possible since we don't have access to the external party's code?

Side note: Due to Wix's limitations, I am unable to insert external stylesheets/scripts or inject anything into the header. All code must be accomplished within the constraints of the < body > tags in their i-frame/html widget.

Thanks in advance! I've already learned so much from the awesome forum members and greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is logical but you have to have a script written at their side that matches with your data otherwise you are trying to hack if you do not create some kind of an API between you two parties. They will have to permit you at their site first

Comment: Okay. That's what I was afraid of. The existing site does currently have this mirroring option, but I don't know what the previous site owner's relationship with the 3rd party was. Thanks for the response!

Comment: You could try a little harder way to tackle it. First take a good look at the page of the page you want to log into. If they are using forms with their method and action tags right there then you can use the fields they used from your own site but if they are advanced you will have to track their javascript you may see what how they passed their forms and a little more logic can get you into their site. Happy coding